# zeep requests.exceptions.SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",)

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, python-requests, zeep

I try to create SOAP Client with the help of zeep lib for python

```
import os
from zeep import Client
from zeep.wsse.signature import Signature

key_filename = "/etc/ssl/certs/cert.key.pem"
cert_filename = "/etc/ssl/certs/cert.crt.pem"

client = Client('https://37.230.149.6:10004/emias-soap-service/PGUServicesInfo2?wsdl', wsse=Signature(key_filename, cert_filename))
```

And have this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/max/bot_project/Bots_Django/TelegramBot/bot/simple_soap_client.py", line 19, in <module>
    wsse=Signature(key_filename, cert_filename))
  File "/home/max/bot_project/Bots_Django/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zeep/client.py", line 120, in __init__
    self.wsdl = Document(wsdl, self.transport, strict=strict)
  File "/home/max/bot_project/Bots_Django/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zeep/wsdl/wsdl.py", line 76, in __init__
    document = self._get_xml_document(location)
  File "/home/max/bot_project/Bots_Django/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zeep/wsdl/wsdl.py", line 137, in _get_xml_document
    location, self.transport, self.location, strict=self.strict)
  File "/home/max/bot_project/Bots_Django/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zeep/loader.py", line 66, in load_external
    content = transport.load(url)
  File "/home/max/bot_project/Bots_Django/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zeep/transports.py", line 111, in load
    content = self._load_remote_data(url)
  File "/home/max/bot_project/Bots_Django/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zeep/transports.py", line 126, in _load_remote_data
    response = self.session.get(url, timeout=self.load_timeout)
  File "/home/max/bot_project/Bots_Django/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 501, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/max/bot_project/Bots_Django/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/max/bot_project/Bots_Django/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/max/bot_project/Bots_Django/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 497, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",)
```

How can I fix this exception and what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me-

```
session.verify = False
```

Comment: This gives the error: name 'sessions' is not defined.

Can you add the import for sessions for your solution?

Comment: @Sankalp Please also mention where the `session` variable came from. This is an incomplete answer.

Answer (score 6):

Explicitly pass a `Session` object to your zeep `Client` (via a `Transport` object) and set `verify=False`

Here's an example:

```py
from requests import Session
from zeep import Client
from zeep.transports import Transport
from zeep.wsse.signature import Signature

import os

key_filename = "/etc/ssl/certs/cert.key.pem"
cert_filename = "/etc/ssl/certs/cert.crt.pem"

session = Session()
session.verify = False

client = Client(
    'https://37.230.149.6:10004/emias-soap-service/PGUServicesInfo2?wsdl',
    wsse=Signature(key_filename, cert_filename),
    transport=Transport(session=session)
)
```

Alternatively, also the way you should do it, is to set `session.verify` to a CA Authority certificate (the issuer of the certificate installed on your server ROOT and SUB certificates), example:

```
session.verify = "/path/to/ca_cert.pem"
```

This will basically tell your python script to trust the URL if the issuer of the certificate is the same as the one in `ca_cert.pem`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need use `verify=False`

Answer (score 0):

```
client = Client(wsdl=wsdl_url)
client.transport.session.verify = False
```